# JointJS: Add SVG to the center of a link

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

I know it is possible to create custom link ends in JointJS using SVG as demonstrated [here](http://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/link-styling). However, I don't know how one can create custom shapes that stay at the center of the link. I only know one can put labels there.

Answer (score 1):

The shapes that you see at the ends of the link are paths tags with shapes, you can customize a link to add a new path shape to show up in the center. Sorry i do not have an example with me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Just add the path with attr connection: true and ref your svg to this path.

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Comment: It would be nice if instead (or additionally) to the screenshot you could post the relevant code in a code block, as it makes it easier to copy it.